# Unable to read POST data from listbox

Tags: php, mysql, listbox

Here is what i am doing I have 2 db tables:

1. cameras with field name and other fields
2. users with email id and other fields

I have populated them using list box and I am able to retrieve data from the MySQL db. I use a form to post data and later capture it. Here is my piece of code:

```
<form action="share.php" method="post">
Camera Name:
 <select>
<?php
while($fetch_options1 = mysql_fetch_array($data1)) { //Loop all the options retrieved from the query
?>
<option id ="<?php echo $fetch_options1['id']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $fetch_options1['name']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_options1['name']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
Share With Email ID:
 <select>
<?php
while($fetch_options = mysql_fetch_array($data)) { 
?>

<option id ="<?php echo $fetch_options['id']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $fetch_options['email']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_options['email']; ?></option>

<?php } ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Share The camera">
</form>
```

And on the same page I use this code to get the posted values, which does not give me any answer:

```
<?php   
// START FORM PROCESSING
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.
    $errors = array();

    $_POST= array('name'=>'','email'=>'');

    echo $cname = $_POST['name'];
    echo $email1 = $_POST['email'];
    echo $user_id=$_SESSION['id'];

} else { // Form has not been submitted.        
}
?>
```

I want to get the selected email id and name from the list box when the user hits submit. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your SELECTs:

```
 <SELECT name="selCamera" id="selCamera">
 ...
 </SELECT>
 <SELECT name="selEmail" id="selEmail">
 ...
 </SELECT>
```

Then in your PHP:

```
 $camera=$_POST['selCamera'];
 $email=$_POST['selEmail'];
```

I dont't understand why you are doing the `$_POST=array(...` thing, leave it out if you choose this solution.

Comment: i was using $_POST=array(.. because i was getting error undefined index name for variables in $_POST['name'];.
Thanks i got the sollution